# How to update a value in destructing and loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga, self-destruction

**What I try to achieve**:

I want to update a value in an obj, which is part of the element of array. See the code below will give you better idea.

There is an issue that I update the value of object, via reference, instead of making a **copy**. This causes the state behave strangely.

I try to change it to **making a copy**, but I am not sure.

e.g.

```
const returnObj = {
  ...objs,
  fields: [{name, value}, {name, value}, {name, value_update_this_only}, ...],
};
```

```
// This is the current code
export function* onChange(action) {
  // get partial state from redux state
  const list = yield select((state) => state.list);
  let objs = list[action.index];

  // * e.g. objs.fields === [{name, value}, {name, value}, ...]
  // * basically following, find the correct field and update its value
  // * following has problem, beause we change the value of a reference,
  // * instead we should make a new copy, so redux can react
  objs.fields.map((field) => {
    if (field.name === action.fieldName) {
      field["value"] = action.fieldValue;
    }
    return field;
  });

  // fire to redux reducer
  yield put({
    type: "UPDATE",
    prop: obj,
    docIndex: action.index,
  });
}

// the problem: I don't know how to do it in destructing manner.
const returnObj = {
  ...objs,
  fields: [],
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think rather than try and come up with a single destructuring statement that makes this work, it's easier to digest (and arguably more readable) in smaller steps:

1. Make a shallow copy of `objs`; call it `copy` for now
2. Recreate `fields` array and every item within it
3. For the desired array item, update its `value`
4. Set the `copy.fields` to the array created in 2

```js
// Step 1: Shallow copy
let copy = { ...objs }

// Step 2: Recreate fields and every item
let fields = copy.fields.map((field) => ({
  ...field
}))

// Step 3: Update value of desired item
fields.forEach((field) => {
  if (field.name === action.fieldName)
    field.value = action.fieldValue
})

// Step 4: Reassign fields to the copy
copy.fields = fields
```

Refactoring this, steps 2-4 can be combined into one step without sacrificing that much readability:

```js
let copy = { ...objs }

copy.fields = copy.fields.map((field) => ({
  ...field,
  value: field.name === action.fieldName ? action.fieldValue : field.value,
}))
```

It's been a long time since I've used redux or sagas, so I'm not sure whether `fields` needs to be an entirely new array or if just the changed object within `fields` needs to be new, but the above can be modified to accommodate either need.